Unity new input system issue
Getting error:
NullReferenceException while executing 'performed' callbacks of 'Player/Interact[/Keyboard/e]'
UnityEngine.InputSystem.LowLevel.NativeInputRuntime/<>c__DisplayClass7_0:<set_onUpdate>b__0 (UnityEngineInternal.Input.NativeInputUpdateType,UnityEngineInternal.Input.NativeInputEventBuffer*)
UnityEngineInternal.Input.NativeInputSystem:NotifyUpdate (UnityEngineInternal.Input.NativeInputUpdateType,intptr)
when pressing e to interact with a GameObject in new input system.
